# Same controller action being invoked in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure what is going on but even though I am invoking a different controller with action a particular FooController's Index action is being invoked all the time. The Global.asax file has setup the FooController to be the default controller.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "FooController", action = "SomeAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

Comment: Could you add the URLs for that you're trying to test this for, for more information.

Comment: show your routes declared in your Global.asax and how you're generating your ActionLink, please

Comment: Well the url is something like the following: http://localhost:33223/us/en/11/ and then it invokes the FooController index action.

Comment: Please post the part of the code where you register your routes, with the RouteCollection

Comment: sounds right to me. If we saw your routes we could tell you why it's happening

Comment: updated the code! Nothing special in the RegisterRoutes!

Comment: When you say "particular", do you mean that a particular *instance* of the controller keeps getting hit, or that regardless of URL the Index() action keeps getting hit, but on a different instance of the controller?

Comment: The same controller "FooController" and its "Index" action is hit even if I am trying to browse a different controller's action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following route definition:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "FooController", action = "SomeAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

if you call `http://localhost:33223/us/en/11` in the absence of a `UsController` you will get a 404 exception.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your comment?

Comment: if I call like this: http://localhost:33223/us/Foo/FooAction then it works. If I call http://localhost:33223/us/Boo/BooAction then it will trigger the FooController's FooAction.

Comment: Where does this `us` come from? Is it the name of the virtual directory your application is hosted to?

Comment: I have no idea! Actually I got the latest source after deleting the complete app and now it is working fine. Thanks for yr help!